# Configure helm to connect to nexus

Tags: nexus, kubernetes-helm, nexus3

I searched on internet to find a tutorial to connect helm with nexus, without success. 
DO you know a tutorial who can help me to do that ?
i found [that one](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Helm+Chart+Repositories)

but they dont tell how to configure a registery on nexus to add helm packages .

Thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: As of 3.21 (deployed 2020-02-18), Helm is automatically in NXRM3 and connection steps are documented on https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Helm+Repositories rather than in GitHub since it's no longer a plugin.  The below will just be used for older instances and anyone making their own modifications to the plugin not using NXRM internal codebase.

---

https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-helm/blob/master/README.md I believe is what you're looking for.

If you need further help with the plugin, you can try an issue on that project or asking in [gitter](https://gitter.im/sonatype/nexus-oss).